# Admob shows Test ads but my ads not showing

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, testing, admob

I'm using Admob for showing Android ads. My real ads are not showing but when I try the test code it works.
I tried my ads in another game and it works. I created this game using buildbox

```
private static AdRequest getAdRequest(){
    // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
    // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            // uncomment to get test ads
            //.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
            .build();
    return adRequest;
```

Comment: upload your logs as well

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.secrethq.ads;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

public class PTAdAdMobBridge {
    private static final String TAG = "PTAdAdMobBridge";
    private static Cocos2dxActivity activity;
    private static WeakReference<Cocos2dxActivity> s_activity;
    private static AdView adView;
    private static InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private static LinearLayout layout;

    private static native String bannerId();
    private static native String interstitialId();
    private static native void interstitialDidFail();
    private static native void bannerDidFail();

    private static boolean isBannerScheduledForShow = false;
    private static boolean isInterstitialScheduledForShow = false;

    public static void initBridge(Cocos2dxActivity activity){
        Log.v(TAG, "PTAdAdMobBridge  -- INIT");


        PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity = new WeakReference<Cocos2dxActivity>(activity); 
        PTAdAdMobBridge.activity = activity;

        MobileAds.initialize(PTAdAdMobBridge.activity, PTAdAdMobBridge.bannerId());

        PTAdAdMobBridge.initBanner();
        PTAdAdMobBridge.initInterstitial();

    }

    public static void initBanner(){
        Log.v(TAG, "PTAdAdMobBridge  -- initBanner");
        PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView != null){
                    return;
                }

                FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)PTAdAdMobBridge.activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout( PTAdAdMobBridge.activity );
                frameLayout.addView( layout );

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        AdView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                adViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView = new AdView( PTAdAdMobBridge.activity );
                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setAdUnitId( PTAdAdMobBridge.bannerId() );

                layout.addView(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView, adViewParams);
                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );

                AdRequest adRequest = getAdRequest();
                PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.loadAd( adRequest );     
            }
        });

    }

    public static boolean isBannerVisible(){
        if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView == null){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void initInterstitial(){
        Log.v(TAG, "PTAdAdMobBridge  -- initInterstitial");
        PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial != null){
                    return;
                }

                AdRequest adRequest = getAdRequest();

                PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial = new InterstitialAd( PTAdAdMobBridge.activity );
                PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.setAdUnitId( PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitialId() );
                PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        if(PTAdAdMobBridge.isInterstitialScheduledForShow){
                            PTAdAdMobBridge.showFullScreen();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                        PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        if ( !isInterstitialScheduledForShow )
                            return;

                        PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitialDidFail();
                    }
                });

                PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
        });
    }



    public static void showFullScreen(){
        Log.v(TAG, "showFullScreen");

        isInterstitialScheduledForShow = true;

        if(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial != null){
            PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.isLoaded()){
                        PTAdAdMobBridge.interstitial.show();
                        PTAdAdMobBridge.isInterstitialScheduledForShow = false;
                    }
                    else{
                        PTAdAdMobBridge.isInterstitialScheduledForShow = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }



    public static void showBannerAd(){
        Log.v(TAG, "showBannerAd");

        isBannerScheduledForShow = true;

        if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView != null){
            PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    AdRequest adRequest = getAdRequest();

                    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.loadAd(adRequest);
                    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {                 
                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                            if ( !isBannerScheduledForShow )
                                return;

                            Log.v(TAG, "Banner Ad Failed To Load");
                            PTAdAdMobBridge.bannerDidFail();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdLoaded() {
                            Log.v(TAG, "Banner Ad Loaded");
                            PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( isBannerScheduledForShow ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE );
                        }
                    });
                    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                }
            });         
        }



    }

    public static void hideBannerAd(){
        Log.v(TAG, "hideBannerAd");

        isBannerScheduledForShow = false;

        if(PTAdAdMobBridge.adView != null){
            PTAdAdMobBridge.s_activity.get().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    PTAdAdMobBridge.adView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static AdRequest getAdRequest(){
        // Create an ad request. Check your logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
        // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                // uncomment to get test ads
                //.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")
                .build();
        return adRequest;
    }

}
```